# rails 4 deployment - not displaying the home page , only the list of files in public

Tags: apache, ruby-on-rails-4

I deployed my rails 4 app on my remote server ( Debian 7) w Capistrano3 wo any error ..
but when I hit the url in a browser ( http://www.ceramique-isabelle.fr) I can see the list of files/folders in the current release directory...

it's deployed into /var/www/rails/production/workshop on the rmeote server ,

and I have in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ceramique-isabelle.fr a vhost

```
        <VirtualHost *:80>
         ServerAdmin webmaster@webdufour.com
         ServerName ceramique-isabelle.fr
         ServerAlias www.ceramique-isabelle.fr
         DocumentRoot /var/www/rails/production/workshop/current/public
         setenv RAILS_ENV production
        <Directory /var/www/rails/production/workshop/current/public>
            AllowOverride All
            RailsEnv production
            Options -MultiViews
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/workshop_error_log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/workshop_access_log common
    </VirtualHost>
```

I also enabled the site a2ensite ceramique-isabelle.fr
and reloaded apache2

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to reinstall Passenger afte switching from rbvm to rbenv  ..

```
gem install passenger
rbenv rehash
sudo bash -c "source ~/.bashrc && passenger-install-apache2-module"
```

then modifying my apache2.conf

and restarting apache2... now up and running